# How to set the lineWidth for a single input component in antd

Tags: javascript, antd

Why is the lineWidth not getting applied to the following input in antd:

```
 import * as stylex from '@stylexjs/stylex';
 import { Input } from "antd";
    
    const styles = stylex.create({
        input: {
            lineWidth: 2
        }
    });
...
    <Input {...stylex.props(styles.input)} type="email" size="large" autoFocus />
...
```

However if I set it in my root ConfigProvider as shown below it works:

```
<ConfigProvider
    theme={{
        components: {
            Input: {
                lineWidth: 2
            }
        }
    }}
>
```

I don't want the lineWidth to affect all my inputs. I need this specifically for only one input element.

Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, what exactly you mean by line width, check this reference https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/index.php .

Comment: @AkalankaDissanayake I know what a lineWidth is. Check my updated question.

Comment: @ololo I believe they are asking what this `lineWidth` property is, a quick search doesn't find anything by that name relating to CSS.

Comment: Got your point (y)

Answer (score 0):

The line width property isn't standard CSS property, Which might be the reason its not taking effect. You can use border width CSS instead.

```
const styles = stylex.create({
    input: {
        borderBottomWidth: "4px"
    }
});
```